# Editing text file with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a utility in python that will list the text files in the current directory, let the user choose a file and then open that file in a text editor. How do you reference an array in the os.system command?

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = os.getcwd()
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]

cnt = 0
for s in onlyfiles:
    cnt += 1
    print "%d : %s" % (cnt,s)
choice = raw_input("Select file: ")
os.system("kate onlyfiles[choice]")
```

Comment: [String concatenation](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python)

Comment: Hint: Look at your `print` line: You already know how to format strings.

Comment: Since you're dealing with user input, you're better off using the `subprocess` module, since this will work for *any* input you give it, including spaces, or special shell characters. `subprocess` will accept a `list`, see the docs. You could also use the `shlex` module to escape the input, but that's not as easy or foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system('kate "{}"'.format(onlyfiles[int(choice) - 1]))
```

Better solution would be:

```
subprocess.call(['vim', '{}'.format(onlyfiles[int(choice) - 1])])
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help. I'll look into subprocess

```
os.system("kate %s " % onlyfiles[int(choice)])
```

Comment: ah thanks, spaces in files names are evil, I'll think about how to handle that.